# How to reorder Adobe Illustrator scripts in `File Menu > Scripts`?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript, photoshop-script

In [Illustrator Scripting Guide](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html) under **Installing scripts in the Scripts Menu**, it shows how we can put our scripts in presets directory. Is it possible to organize these scripts the way Adobe Photoshop does?

[image: Adobe Photoshop Scripts Menu]

Looking at [Image Processor.jsx](https://github.com/LeZuse/photoshop-scripts/blob/master/default/Image%20Processor.jsx), we can see this interesting snippet:

```js
/*
// BEGIN__HARVEST_EXCEPTION_ZSTRING
<javascriptresource>
<name>$$$/JavaScripts/ImageProcessor/Menu=Image Processor...</name>
<category>aaaThisPutsMeAtTheTopOfTheMenu</category>
<eventid>1F9021B1-5045-42E1-AE2A-7E504FAA8D50</eventid>
</javascriptresource>
// END__HARVEST_EXCEPTION_ZSTRING
*/
```

Can someone help me make sense of these lines and how do I implement it on [my own scripts](https://github.com/hendraanggrian/prepress-adobe-scripts)?

Comment: This [link](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/add-customize-menu/td-p/10574634?page=1) might be able to help you. The `eventid` is a UUID. But then it gets more ccomplicated with `<terminology><![CDATA[<< /Version 1 
                         /Events << 
                          /a0754df2-9c60-4b64-a940-6a2bb1102652 [($$$/JavaScripts/DeleteAllEmptyLayers/Menu=Delete All Empty Layers) /noDirectParam <<
                          >>] 
                         >> 
                      >> ]]></terminology>
</javascriptresource>`

Comment: That link is a good read, I now know we can put our scripts in some or all of the existing menus instead of only `File Menu > Scripts`.  However, it seems like only Photoshop recognize those `javascriptresource` tag. In my test Illustrator just straight ignored it.